# How to pass variables to a view in Express?

Tags: node.js, express

I am quite new to Express.js/Node.js and trying to pass multiple values from a route to a view so that I am able to show user specific input on the page. This is what I have in my route:

```
// Dashboard for site after the login
app.get('/dashboard', function(req, res) {
 res.render('dashboard.jade', {
  title: 'Dashboard',
  user: app.get('user_name')
 });
});
```

I have stored the user name in `app.get('user_name')`. If I replace it with a normal string like `'test string'` than it works. But if I use this `app.get` function nothing is getting passed to the view.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using app.locals documented here: http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.locals

Comment: i tried using app.locals and then switched back using app.get / app.set somehow it was working after i have restarted nodemon ;-) but i agree most likely app.locals would be the better choice. thanks